# How to find difference between two arraylist in java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have two arraylist with a number of model objects.I want to find the difference of these arraylists.When I use strings instead of  models, I got the difference with removeall function in collection framework. But for model objects it doesnot work. Please any one help me

Comment: What do you mean by comparing two ArrayLists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement `equals` and `hashCode` in your custom object and you can use the same approach as you did with `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `removeAll` method is a generic library method which doesn't know *anything* about your model class.  So if you think about it for a second, how is it going to know which ones are "the same"?

The short answer is that you need to [override the `equals()` method](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) in your `Model` class, as this is what the checks are based on.  The implementation should return true for any pair of model instances that you wish to be considered the same - the default inherited behaviour returns true only if they're the same object in memory.  (And as always, when you override `equals()` you [must override `hashCode()` too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)).

Answer (score 0):

`String` class has already overridden version of `equals` and `hashCode` method so you are able to use `remove()` method. If you have to use your class in collection  `(List or Set)` then you will have to override these methods in your class otherwise it will use default implementation of these methods.

If two objects are logically equal that means their `hashCode` must be equal as well as they satisfy equals().

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two ArraList you need two compare two objects.In your case it is your model object,for that you need to override equals method.
Try this code
 @Override
        public boolean equals(Object compareObj)
        {
        if (this == compareObj) 
               return true;

```
    if (compareObj == null) 
        return false;

    if (!(compareObj instanceof MyModel)) 
        return false;

    MyModel model = (MyModel)compareObj; 

    return this.name.equals(model.name); // Are they equal?
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
    int primeNumber = 31;
    return primeNumber + this.name.hashCode();
        return 0;
    }
```